# Map undefined in ReactJS code for todo list app

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, getjson

I just started coding in ReactJS and have to build a todo application. Now there is a problem when displaying to-do items received from an API call. This is the error I get:

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined***

This is the code:

**TodoList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import TodoItem from './TodoItem';

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

    this.state = {
        todos: [
            {id: 0, title: "", completed: false}
        ]
    };
}


componentDidMount() {
    this.loadTodos();
}

loadTodos(event) {
    let component = this;

    $.getJSON(`https://whispering-thicket-55256.herokuapp.com/todos.json`, function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        component.setState({
            todos: data.todos
        });
    });
}

renderTodos(todo, i) {
    return (
        <TodoItem
            key={todo.id}
            id={todo.id}
            title={todo.title}
            completed={todo.completed}
            createdAt={todo.created_at}
            updatedAt={todo.updated_at} />
    );
}

render() {
    let todos = this.state.todos
return (
  <div>
            <ul>
        {todos.map(this.renderTodos.bind(this))}
      </ul>
  </div>
);
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```

**TodoItem.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import jQuery from 'jquery';

class TodoItem extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            id: this.props.id,
            title: this.props.title,
            completed: this.props.completed,
            createdAt: this.props.createdAt,
            updatedAt: this.props.updatedAt
        })
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
    return (
            <li>{this.props.title}</li>
    );
  }
}

export default TodoItem;
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong here .. Hope someone can help me. What I want to achieve is to display all to-do items from the .json url in a list.
If you need more code (app.js?) then I'll post that too!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that todos isn't initialized when render is called, or that your Ajax call isn't returning what you expect.

Try checking that todos is defined before rendering

```
todos && todos.map...
```

Also check that your Ajax response is what you need it to be.